# MySQL query when grouping duplicate records

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to write a query that will find all of our sku's that have option that are a mix of drop downs and swatches.

We have a table that stores this info but is set up a little weird. The column that are important to me are.

```
-------------------------------------------
sku | option_flag | swatch_flag | sequence
-------------------------------------------
```

There can be multiple duplicate records of sku because the other columns change depending of how the sku is set up.

My expected results would look like this.

```
-------------------------------------------
 sku  | option_flag | swatch_flag | sequence
-------------------------------------------
aa001 |      YES    |    NO       |     1
-------------------------------------------
aa001 |      YES    |    YES      |     2
-------------------------------------------
aa001 |      YES    |    NO       |     3
-------------------------------------------
```

So far I have this and it is grouping by the sku but it is still including no for option_flag. Maybe instead of grouping by sku, is there a way to ask to sort it by the sequence 1 2 3 - 1 2 3 etc.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM sku_parent_attributes AS a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sku
    FROM sku_parent_attributes
    WHERE option_flag = 'yes'
    GROUP BY sku
    HAVING COUNT(sku) = 3) AS b
ON a.sku = b.sku;
```

Comment: Why are you using the `INNER JOIN` at all? If you are pulling from the same table why not just include the conditions in your select?  `SELECT a.*
FROM sku_parent_attributes WHERE option_flag='YES'...`

Comment: I was just trying to get something to work. I doesn't have to be a inner join.

Comment: @JoshLesch can you provide some sample data? your question is not clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.sku
FROM sku_parent_attributes AS a
INNER JOIN
sku_parent_attributes as b
ON a.sku = b.sku
GROUP BY b.sku
HAVING COUNT(b.sku) = 3
```

the where condition inside the full query and not only inside of the subquery.